# How to start multiple altcoin rpc daemons at once?

Tags: bitcoind, altcoin

I'm building an ecommerce website where I want to do my own payment processing in seven different ctyptocurrencies. I want use the separate versions of bitcoind for each currency, because I feel like that's the most straightforward way to do it (unless I'm wrong). I've even come up with some dog simple interface code to use once I get them all running!

So I've compiled each one, and I've got my rpc config files ready and raring to go, but whenever I start one of the rpc servers... it doesn't exit to the command line. It either just sits there, or depending on whether or not I'm printing to the console, it tells me everything that's happening.

When I hit cntrl+c, it exits to the command line, without stopping the daemon, which is what I want, but I can't seem to figure out how to write a script that will start all of the different rpc servers at once.

I have to be missing something stupidly basic.

I've looked everywhere on this stack exchange, and have not been able to find a solution to this problem.

HELP!

Thanks in advance for your time and attention.

Edit: I'm attempting to do this from the Linux command line with the standard compile parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your conf file to include

server=1

daemon=1

Or you can also pass these in at the command line

You can see these on the Wiki

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Running_Bitcoin

Answer (score 0):

> in seven different ctyptocurrencies

Not a good idea. Trust me. Bitcoin is enough, and for that you don't need any daemons. Bitpay or blockchain.info can handle it for you.

Well, here is what I do to start Litecoin daemon:

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Litecoin\litecoin-qt.exe" -server -rpcallowip=127.0.0.1 -rpcuser=user -rpcpassword=password -rpcport=1488

Comment: Right on. Actually, I'm not accepting bitcoin at all. The whole thing is an exercise in building altcoin economies. I have some theories about the nature of speculative assets that I want to prove or disprove.

I actually did try what you're outlining. It still hangs after I start it.

Comment: In Windows 7 after I run it waits for two seconds and starts the client.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu with no ui. Just using the daemons.

Comment: Use Windows. Most altcoins don't even have clients for Linux.